# Different phases of Android app running in phone?

Tags: android, runtime, apk

I have been getting this question again and again from people in interviews that define different phases of Android app launch from Android OS.
I have never heard of that. What are those phases?
What I heard of is different methods of lifecycle of components like Activity, Fragments, Services etc.
Plz clear confusion.

Comment: It sounds like lifecycle talk. Did they say it wasn't?

Comment: This may be related to launch modes I guess but not sure.